# 競プロで、自分が書いたプログラム(Acceptされない)と正答例の違いが不明

Tags: python, python3

中間試験、期末試験、再試験の点数から成績を出力するプログラムなのですが、([ITP1_7_A](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=ITP1_7_A&lang=ja)です)
自分のコードは提出してもACにならず、一方で正答例のコードはACされています。

何故自分のコードが正解にならないのかが分からなくなってしまったので、どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

**自分のコード:**

```
m = 0
f = 0

while True:
  m, f ,r = map(int, input().split())
  s = m + f
  if m == -1 and f == -1 and r == -1:
    break
  if m == -1 or f == -1:
    g = "F"
  if s >= 80:
    g = "A"
  elif s >= 65:
    g = "B"
  elif s >= 50:
    g = "C"
  elif s >= 30:
    if r >= 50:
      g = "C"
    else:
      g ="D"
  else:
    g ="F"
  print(g)
```

**正答例:**

```
while True:
    M,F,R = map(int,input().split())
    if M == -1 and F == -1 and R == -1:
        break
    if M == -1 or F == -1:
        print("F")
    elif M+F >= 80:
        print("A")
    elif M+F >= 65:
        print("B")
    elif M+F >= 50:
        print("C")
    elif M+F >= 30:
        if R >= 50:
            print("C")
        else:
            print("D")
    else:
        print("F")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

中間試験か期末試験のいずれかを欠席した場合は"F"で確定ですが、そのまま次のIF分に突入しています。
そのため本来は試験欠席により"F"になるはずの学生が他の成績で上書きされてしまっています。

```
  if m == -1 or f == -1:
    g = "F"
  if s >= 80:
    g = "A"
```

そのあたりを正答例と比較して考えてみてください。